# Display time series of open issues in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

I want to have a time series visualization showing the amount of existing open issues per, e.g., week, whose range can be adjusted with the time picker.

Say I have an index with issues, which has `openDate`, `closeDate`, and a list of other fields like, `team`, `department` that I would use to filter the issues shown in the visualization.

In Kibana it would be trivial to show issues opened or closed each week, as counting events is trivial.

However, showing *open issues* is counting *states*. It is not rocket science, if you have a `timeStart` and `timeEnd`, the number of open issues is given by the filter:

```
openDate < timeEnd and (not exists(closeDate) or closeDate>timeStart)
```

Is there any way of solving this with Kibana? I imagine that it is possible to write such a query with ES, but how to link it to the time picker? how to use the values it return in a visualization, etc....

Comment: You can try using saved queries. You can save the query you are interested in. Then use that saved query for the visualization creation.

Comment: @Shaleen how? would it be possible for you to link some example. It is not at all obvious to me how

Comment: I found this link in elastic blog https://www.elastic.co/blog/reusing-saved-queries-in-kibana-across-dashboard-visualize-and-discover

Comment: Ok, reading in that blog entry it says: "Imagine being able to create filters in the filter bar based on saved queries, giving us an easy way to combine existing queries. In a similar vein, we could develop a syntax for referencing saved queries inside a KQL expression. That would allow for effortless reuse of saved queries in places where a query text input is available without the full search bar, like the filters aggregation in Visualize"... So it seems there is a plan of being able to do so in future releases. But it isn't possible yet.

Comment: Please try this - go to discover page on kibana - type thequery which you are interested in - once you are satisfied - save the query by clicking on the save menu. Once you save the query it will be available for you to select for visualization. This feature is available in 7 version atleast, which I am testing.